# Problem with RawSienna

Tags: color

With the following style file I get `Package xcolor Error: Undefined color` RawSienna'.`

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{test-xcolor-galex}[2022/10/03 Andromeda Galaxy Package]

%% Deferred colours (with asterisk) for dvipsnames
\RequirePackage[dvipsnames*,svgnames,x11names]{xcolor}
\definecolors{Lavender}

\renewcommand{\seriesdefault}{\bfdefault}
\boldmath

\catcode`-=11  % make "hyphen" (-) a letter
\newcommand{\teora-pigment}{RawSienna}
\newcommand{\teora-pigm-name}{green!72!black}
\newtheorem{teora}{\color{\teora-pigment}{Theorem}}[section]
\catcode`-=12  % make "hyphen" (-) a letter
```

This is the document

```
\documentclass[b5paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[body={13cm,18cm}]{geometry}

%% Language Tools
\usepackage[italian,french,spanish,icelandic,english]{babel}

\usepackage{test-xcolor-galex}
\usepackage{countriesofeurope}

\begin{document}

aueaoe
\section{Teor} 

\begin{teora}
  Test
\end{teora}

%% \Iceland 

\end{document}
```

Comment: well you haven't defined `RawSienna` (as you used `dvipsnames*` which prevents the names being defined, except `Lavender` which you declare

Comment: The `svgnames` colors will always overrule `dvipsnames` colors with identical names. But `RawSienna` in only defined in `dvipsnames`.  The `xcolor` manual seems to suggest that only identical names require definition.

Comment: No it disables all the names but why are you loading all these names anyway??

Comment: I am testing to see what happens and learn some things.  I did not know that detail of disabling all names.  Perhaps the `xcolor` manual should be clear about that.

Comment: sec 2.4.2 "In
the latter case, individual color names have to be activated by \definecolors or
\providecolors commands, as described in section 2.5.4 on page 20, before they
can be applied in a document." seems fairly clear, but as I say why are you loading _any_ of these names, loading them all just seems excessively weird.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to defer only identically named colours rather than all of them?

Comment: why are you loading muliple conflicting names??? The primary reason for the `*` option is to save memory by not defining the full sets of names, only the ones requested, but you don't need any names here.

Comment: Technically, it should not be a problem.  In reality I have an option that gets you a set of color names available, as I am making a coloured set of theorem environments, where a user can request any colour defined in `xcolor`.

Comment: why restrict to those names?

Comment: One can also use `green!72!black`.  For new users, colour names might be better.

Comment: you can use cmyk 0.2,0.4,1,0.2  or whatever,you are defining hundreds of colors people won't use and not allowing the use of colors that people may choose from a color picker

Comment: What would stop people choosing from colour picker?  I then wonder the utility of `xcolor` options.

Comment: using the options _in a package_  has mostly negative effects, it means your package can't be used in beamer, or loaded after tikz, or xcolor or utfsym or ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A more minimal example would be

```
\documentclass{article}
\RequirePackage[dvipsnames*,svgnames,x11names]{xcolor}
\definecolors{Lavender}
\begin{document}

\color{RawSienna} abc

\end{document}
```

which gives

```
! Package xcolor Error: Undefined color `RawSienna'.
```

as you have not defined the color. I can think of no reason to load xcolor with so many pre-defined color names, but since you have, you can avoid the error by declaring `RawSienna` as well:

```
\documentclass{article}
\RequirePackage[dvipsnames*,svgnames,x11names]{xcolor}
\definecolors{Lavender,RawSienna}
\begin{document}

\color{RawSienna} abc

\end{document}
```